# How to check 3ware raid controller's health? (Where to download tw_cli tool?)

Tags: centos, raid, hardware-raid

I have a 3ware controller and I would like to check the health of the drives and the raid itself.

I found this blog: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-check-health-of-3ware-raid-array/

but I couldnt find the app `tw_cli-linux-x86_64-9.4.1.3.tgz` he mentioned and the command did not work.

So how can I check the health of the hard disks I have in my RAID? and what information do I need to provide to my datacenter for them to be able to identify the broken drive and replace it?

Its a 3ware RAID 10 with 8 drives attached.

Comment: The one from fau.de servers seems authentic: http://ftp.fau.de/gentoo/distfiles/tw_cli-linux-x86_64-9.5.3.tgz
Though version 9.5.3 may not work for you. Another download option which seems fine is http://www.ayksolutions.com/tw_cli.zip (contains version 9.5.4).

Answer (score 1):

Find out your exact controller model, go to the [3ware homepage](http://www.3ware.com/products/serial_ata.asp) and search for your model. You will get the option to download the necessary tools.